# Android Navigation drawer: How to change actionBarMenu according to drawer list item select

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation drawer in my app. It has a list of items. I use a switch statement and replace a current Fragment with a completely new Fragment which has its own views and logic.

> 

My problem is that each Fragment has its own menu item in the action bar. I don't know how to change the actionBar menu item according to the selected drawer list item. I have tried lots of tutorials and ended with no result. Some sample code would really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you want to change the style of menu or want to know how to create new menu for action bar??

Comment: Want to create new menu for action bar..

Comment: chk my answer any doubt just ask ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this tutorial is exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

create  menuitemlist.xml  in your menu folder. You can define your menu and sub menu here. EX:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:icon="@drawable/filter_data"
    android:title="projectlist"
    android:titleCondensed="FILTER">
      <menu> 
           <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:title="Search"/>

    </menu>


</item>


<item
    android:id="@+id/profilename"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="details"
    android:titleCondensed="fullmode">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="here"
    android:titleCondensed="about">
    <menu> 

    <item
            android:id="@+id/it1"
            android:title="list1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/it2"
            android:title="list2"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/it3"
            android:title="list3"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/admin"
    android:icon="@drawable/admin"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="welcome"
    android:titleCondensed="welcome">
</item>
```

In activity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitemlist, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

For More Check 
 http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project and enjoy with action bar .`

Comment: I think Kevin van Mierlo's answer will helpful to me. I just started to work and thanks to your valuable reply.